# Webdriver test doesn't select option from dropdown

Tags: java

i have a registration form for checkout,I have to select a state from drop down,for which i have written a script:

```
WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.name("user_data[s_state]")) ;

Select selwb = new Select(wb) ;

selwb.selectByValue("KR");

driver.findElement(By.name("dispatch[checkout.update_steps]")).click() ;
```

but after executing this script,it is not selecting given value from dropdown.hence i am unable to proceed on next step. Plz help me out....

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a suggestion since I have worked with Selenium webdriver for sometime. The webdriver executes very fastly. Selenium driver doesnt take care whether the page loaded or not. So I recommend you to add code just before the click/selection events to make sure that the page loaded completely. There are options like waitForPageLoad() or checkifComponent exist  to make sure that page is loaded properly before the events are triggered. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If any wait doesn't help - like suggested before - try to select eg. by index or text.
I've had such wired cases where one of ByValue/ByText/ByIndex method didn't work although others did with particular dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to select the drop down use the following:

1. First make the webdriver wait
2. Then try choosing the element with the help of 
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the value").select

OR

you can use like the following:

new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("the xpath of the value"))).click();